# Using Python's Higher Order Functions on a CSV

Tags: python, csv, higher-order-functions

I have a csv containing ~45,000 rows, which equates to seven days' worth of data. It has been sorted by datetime, with the oldest record first.

This is a sample row once the csv has been passed into the `csv` module's `DictReader`:

```
{'end': '423', 'g': '2', 'endid': '17131', 'slat': '40.7', 'endname': 'Horchata', 'cid': '1', 'startname': 'Sriracha', 'startid': '521', 'slon': '-73.9', 'usertype': 'Sub', 'stoptime': '2015-02-01 00:14:00+00', 'elong': '-73.9', 'starttime': '2015-02-01 00:00:00+00', 'elat': '40.7', 'dur': '801', 'meppy': '', 'birth_year': '1978'}
```

...and another:

```
{'end': '418', 'g': '1', 'endid': '17108', 'slat': '40.7', 'endname': 'Guacamole', 'cid': '1', 'startname': 'Cerveza', 'startid': '519', 'slon': '-73.9', 'usertype': 'Sub', 'stoptime': '2015-02-01 00:14:00+00', 'elong': '-73.9', 'starttime': '2015-02-02 00:00:00+00', 'elat': '40.7', 'dur': '980', 'meppy': '', 'birth_year': '1983'}
```

I recently wrote the code below. It runs through the csv (after it's been passed to `DictReader`). The code yields the first row of each new day, i.e. whenever the day changes, based on `starttime`:

```
dayList = []
def first_ride(reader):
        for row in reader:
            starttime = dateutil.parser.parse(row['starttime'])
            if starttime.day not in dayList:
                day_holder.append(starttime.day)
                yield row        
            else: 
                pass
```

My goal now is to produce a single list containing the value associated with `birth_year` from each of the seven records, i.e.:

`[1992, 1967, 1988, 1977, 1989, 1953, 1949]`

The catch is that I want to understand how to do it using Python's HOFs to the maximum extent possible (i.e. `map`/ `reduce`, and likely `filter`), without the generator (currently used in my code), and without global variables. To eliminate the global variable, my guess is that each `starttime`'s day will have to be compared to the one before, but not using the list, as I currently have it set up. As a final FYI, I run Python 2.7.

I majorly appreciate any expertise donated.

Comment: What exactly is your question? This isn't a tutorial service.

Comment: This sounds like a ideal job for pandas, why are you looking at reduce for this? Also your else pass is redundant

Comment: Since the list is sorted by time, use itertools.groupby to aggregate by day or year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `reduce` the `dayList`, into a list of `birth_years`:

```
reduce(lambda r, d: r + [d['birth_year']], dayList, [])
```

Or you can use a comprehension (preferred):

```
[d['birth_year'] for d in dayList]
```